# Installing Masonry in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is my first post and I am fairly new to WordPress so please go easy on me for asking stupid questions.

Currently I am attempting to install Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ into a child theme based off of the standard Twenty Eleven theme that comes with WordPress.

I have followed directions from about 20 different tutorials and have no clue why I can not get it to work. I am specifically trying to get it to work for dev project http://www.ct-social.com/ctsdev/aff/our-trips/

Any advice that could lead me in the correct direction. Maybe someone can actually tell me what I am doing wrong.

Update 11/30/12
I have changed the scrip to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var $container = $('.container');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.featured',
      singleMode:true
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

and the html is structured as such:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="featured">
      Stuff inside
  </div>
</div>
```

Still no luck. Any Ideas?

Comment: There are no stupid questions. We were all just starting out at one point.

Comment: +1 for Enrico's comment, if only more people on this site felt the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this

```
var $container = $('#container');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.item',
      columnWidth : 240
    });
  });
```

which fails because your "tiles" all use container as an id and `$('#container')` expects to only find one element. You should not have multiple elements with the same id on the same page.

If you look at the Masonry tutorial example markup

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

there is one div with the id container and each item has the same class.

You need to put all of your items inside a div with the id "container" and add the "featured" class to all the elements you'd like Masonry to tile.

Comment: I have changed my code to have a container with the class items inside as you have specified here, sadly this does not seem to have gotten me any closer to a working masonry page.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You got me headed in the right direction. I'm sure I had it everything correct at one point in time last night, but was missing the vital information you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue and was able to fix my problem.

Instead of enqueuing Jquery within the   did it at the bottom of my functions.php file.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.masonry.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry');
```

Coupled with the changes mentioned by you Enrico, and BOOM! masonry is now working. 
Thank you very much for your help, with-out it I wold still be beating my head against a rock.